# VS Code Как забиндить команду make

Tags: visual-studio-code

Нужно чтоб на F5 открывалась командная строка (та что через <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>) и выполнялась команда `make`.

Comment: Здесь можете найти официальное и исчерпывающее руководство - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings